# Cell won't run on Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, sum, integer

I am trying to make a code block that will find the sum of the first 1000 even integers which looks like this:

```
even_numbers = []

def sum_finder():
    for en in range(2,2000,2):
        even_numbers = en
        print(sum(even_numbers))
```

However, when I run it, nothing happens and it just proceeds to the next In []:

I'm still a beginner, so I'm just trying to figure things out.

Comment: You only define `sum_finder()`, but never run it.

Comment: Then what can I do?

Comment: Add a new line at the end with `sum_finder()` to call it. But your current code will error since `even_numbers = en` will cause `sum(even_numbers)` to raise `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`.

Comment: Also `len(range(2,2000,2)` is only 999 since the end is exclusive. And you can sum a range directly: `sum(range(2, 2002, 2))` -> `1001000`

Answer (score 2):

Your code does the following:

1. Define a variable `even_numbers` and assign an empty array to it.
2. Define a function `sum_finder()`.

You only defined the function but never ran it.
To run it you have to call it. Also your code is a bit off as you assign every even number to the variable `even_number`. I assume you want to add it to your array:

```py
# define the function
def sum_finder():
    even_numbers = []
    for en in range(2,2000,2):
        even_numbers.append(en)
        print(sum(even_numbers))

# call the function
sum_finder()
```

Note that the second parameter in `range()` is not included in that range. So if you want to include 2000, you need to change it to `range(2,2002,2)`. You could also use 2001 as an endpoint here.

Also this code does a sum and print for every sub-range up to 2000. Is this what you want? Or do you only want the final sum of all these numbers? For the latter, you do not even need to write a function but can directly call

```py
summed_even_numbers = sum(range(2, 2002, 2))
print(summed_even_numbers)
```